# Read the story and fill in the blank space

Tags: knowledge, story

**A BOOK YOU CAN RE*A*D TO YOUR KIDS.**

On one of those dim nights, Ed and Nita thought that it feels like a perfect night to paint pictures. After Ed finished painting his, he asked Nita what she thought.

“Er.. remove that rubber duck from the sofa.

It's bringing my attention away from the elk floor lamp next to it.” Said Nita. Ed looked frustrated. “Well, if mine is so bad, what are you painting?”

“First of all, I didn’t say yours was bad, and second I’m painting a very ole RV in Puerto Rico.” Said Nita with a weird accent.

“Nita, Puerto Rico doesn’t have penguins.

And, why’d you put the number 9819 on the side of the RV?” Responded Ed. “That’s not a penguin, it’s a dog dressed as a penguin!” Shouted Nita.

“How was I supposed to know! And why is the beak (BLANK)?” Shouts Ed back.
Nita paints a leg sticking out of the penguin costume and fixes the beak.

“Okay, see? A dog leg now peaks out of the costume so you can tell. And the beak looks normal!” Ed smiles, “Way better!”

Nita rolls her eyes. “One last question about your painting.” Says Ed. Nita stares at him and finally says, “What?” Ed asks, “Uh.. why is the beach called Free Lass Beach?”

“Because I don’t want you on it, it’s only for girls.” She responds. “I was just asking. And now, I'm doing better than I ever was.” “Okay, but, Ed, we should really get to sleep. It’s getting really late.” “You're right.” And they went to bed.

(I also hid a clue not on here.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First I notice:

> In the first paragraph, "dim nights" is an anagram of "midnights."
>
> In the next line, "er remove" is an anagram of "evermore."
>
> Next, "elk floor" anagrams to "folklore."
>
> Then "ole RV" becomes "lover."
>
> "Nita Puerto" rearranges to "reputation."
>
> "9819" is just the digits of "1989" shuffled.
>
> The next line is the one with the blank.
>
> In the remaining lines, "now peaks [sic]" becomes "speak now," and "free lass" is "fearless."

These are

> the names of Taylor Swift's albums listed in reverse order of release date, so the blank in the story can be replaced with the word "[red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_(Taylor_Swift_album))."  Also note that in the heading, the A in "READ" is italicized - if we remove it we're left with just "RED".

Comment: Great job! I knew this puzzle might be a little too easy. But, I still had fun making it. And I also left a hint that you didn't find ;)

Comment: Plus, you missed an anagram. Actually, there's three hints that were missed.

Comment: @LoganSweeney although I have only had a cursory glance at this puzzle at this puzzle it certainly didn’t seem trivial at all and furthermore has a niche topic matter. Have a look at this https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/the-many-eyes-effect

Comment: Actually, you didn't answer exactly right. Those are Taylor's albums, but, when you add the one you missed, they're not just her albums. But, yes RED does fill in the  blank.

Comment: Well done for filling that *Blank Space*...

Comment: I’m not familiar enough with her work probably to have picked up on any other hints.

Comment: Thanks for the idea ;D